# How can i add API key in this Google maps code

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I have played enough with this code.
Mostly from line 1558-1680 but didn't find any solution.

It would be a great help if anyone could help me to add my API key to the link.
I am getting error "no API key" in console and the code works locally but doesn't work online

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8dd127ffb42709348613d3cfcf056c63

credits to CodeXTree this code belongs to them.

PS: sorry for such a huge code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API key belongs at the end of the script tag where you include the Google Maps js in your header or footer.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE"></script>`

The gmaps.js code you linked to gets included below google maps:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/gmaps.js"></script>`